# @Input not Binding data from component

Tags: angular2-forms

Angular2 @Input component is not Binding data from another component

**DummyComponent.ts**

```
import { Component,Input,ElementRef } from "@angular/core"   
@Component({
    selector: "Dummy-Selector",
    template: `Hello Dummy How Are you....`,
  //  inputs: ["rating"]
})
export class DummyComponent {
    debugger;
    @Input() username: string;
}
```

**LoginComponent.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="LoginObj.username" value="user" />

<div>
    <Dummy-Selector [username]='LoginObj.username'></Dummy-Selector>
</div>
```

Here I'm getting my Dummy-selector `username` data but when I insert some data in `LoginObj.username` via the input field - why is it not reflected?

Comment: please take a look at this link for event emitters example and code 

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/inout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what error you are seeing (if any) but it input binding should work with the following:

**LoginComponent.ts**

```
@Component({..})
export class LoginComponent { 
   LoginObj = {};
}
```

In **DummyComponent.ts** change the template to show that the `username` field reflects changes from the `input` field.

```
import { Component,Input } from "@angular/core"   

@Component({
    selector: "Dummy-Selector",
    template: `Hello Dummy How Are you... {{username}}`,
})
export class DummyComponent {
    debugger;
    @Input() username: string;
}
```

Comment: Could u plz post complete code i think its not clear...at all im really new 2 ang2

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Or is the `username` value in DummyComponent not the correct value?